# Post Data and Multiple Image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that has a multiple input data and 4 input image,how do i post them using Ajax ? here is my set of code i have tried...

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('link')?>/to/controller" method="POST" id="frm-update" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!-- Normal Post -->

  <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="form-control">Normal Input1
  <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="form-control">Normal Input2
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="form-control">Normal Input3
  <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" class="form-control">Normal Input4

<!-- Image Post -->

  <input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" class="form-control">Image 1
  <input type="file" name="image2" id="image2" class="form-control">Image 2
  <input type="file" name="image3" id="image3" class="form-control">Image 3
  <input type="file" name="image4" id="image4" class="form-control">Image 4

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$("#frm-update").validate({
  ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn)',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":hidden")) {
            element.next().parent().append(error);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },

 submitHandler: function(form) {
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $("#frm-update").attr('action'),
      data: $("#frm-update").serialize(),

</script>
```

what i've been thinking is,what if i used **new FormData(this)**,do all input on my form is saved ? or is it just the image ?

Comment: this post might help you [jQuery Ajax Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php) (keep in mind that for Ajax upload `contentType: false, processData: false,` are mandatory)

Comment: i already tried that,but it didnt work because i set <form action="...."> into controller...@OldPadawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FormData` instead of `serialize()`

```
$("#frm-update").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn)',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":hidden")) {
            element.next().parent().append(error);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var data = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
               // data passed from php
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then in your `PHP` you can do something like the following

```
<?php

// get values of input through $_POST
// move uploaded files to a directory with move_uploaded_file() function

// get inputs using $_POST
$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
$input2 = $_POST['input2'];
$input3 = $_POST['input3'];
$input4 = $_POST['input4'];

// get files using $_FILES
$image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
$image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
$image3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
$image4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];

// save values to the database
?>
```

Comment: the code works well,the Jquery works,but the image wont post,and i tried to inspect element,the content type was set to text/html; charset=UTF-8,it should be multipart/form-data,isnt it ?

Comment: which image is not getting posted?

Comment: all of them...on database,the image1 - image4 field are set..but the file wont upload to /uploads...so i tried to set the content type manually..and it worked...

Comment: so the images are sent to `PHP` but you can't move them?

Comment: that will do,using your code...but only change the content type manually into multipart/formdata,thank you.....